# Scoring tables in Desmos

Tags: discussion, scoring

There is not a way to copy-paste tables in Desmos & one of my golfs require a table.  How should we score tables?

Comment: Could you provide links to the documentation on tables, or something similar? I'm not very familiar with Desmos and this doesn't give me much to go on.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing that just as I was leaving last period.  [This](https://www.desmos.com/api/v0.6/docs/index.html#document-table-columns) is as close as I can get to documentation.

Comment: Hmm, sadly that isn't a ton to go on. Again, I don't know much about Desmos, but it looks like there should be a way to represent the table using some form of TeX, and that should be a fine score for it.

Comment: Please provide this link: http://ppcg.lol/a/81155

Comment: I already did it