# Language of the Month for May 2022: Desmos

Tags: discussion, language-of-the-month

In accordance with [our meta agreement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/reviving-language-of-the-month-pick-up-where-we-left-off-or-start-over), since one candidate received more votes than the others, we have a new featured language! Throughout May 2022, our Language of the Month will be:

> ## Desmos

### What's a Language of the Month?

See the [meta post for nominations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19279/nominations-for-language-of-the-month-take-2?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top). In short, during May, those who wish to participate should learn (at least the basics of) Desmos, and use it to solve challenges. Participation is completely optional, but is anticipated to be fun!

### Information about Desmos

Desmos is an online graphing calculator with strong mathematical functionalities. It's not designed to be a programming language, but it can certainly be used as one.

### Reasons

- Even though it is a graphing calculator, it can be used as a programming language, albeit a limited one.
- Following the previous point, Desmos has certain limitations that make it fun/challenging to golf with.

  - For example, lists/list manipulation are quite limited; for one, lists can only be 1d, so finding clever ways around that limitation can be interesting.
- Desmos differs from many of the more popular languages in that the code is based on mathematical(\$\LaTeX\$) formulae instead of purely on executing code instructions.
- There is an abundance of builtin functions and functionalities(see **Resources** below) that you can use in your Desmos code.
- There are active communities on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/desmos/),
  [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Desmos), and even [Discord](https://discord.gg/vCBupKs9sB). People there can probably help you with any questions you may have.

### Caveats

- Strings are not supported whatsoever, meaning any challenges requiring string I/O cannot be done with Desmos.
- Sometimes tedious to do the simple, but necessary, golfs every time an expression is copied out from Desmos. (c.f. [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations))

  - e.g.: `\operatorname{min}\left(a,b\right)` --> `min(a,b)`
- Usually very hard to search on the Internet for any questions you may have; you'll most likely have to join one of the communities listed in **Resources** and ask the question there.

### Resources

- [Official website](https://www.desmos.com/)
- [Graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)
- [List of builtin functions](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/212235786-Supported-Functions)
- [Tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230100/tips-for-code-golfing-in-desmos)
- [A comprehensive list of Desmos functionalities](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rlr1sstwye) (credit goes entirely to [@fireflame241](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241) for compiling this list)
- [Desmos updates](https://help.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/4405017454477-What-s-New-at-Desmos)
- Online communities: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/desmos/),
  [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Desmos), [Discord](https://discord.gg/vCBupKs9sB)

### Bounties

I (emanresu A) will award a 50 rep bounty to any user's first Desmos answer this month, and a 200 rep bounty to any user's tenth Desmos answer this month.

Comment: [Desmos chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136024/desmos)

Answer (score 6):

## List of all Desmos answers posted in May 2022

- [Shift right by half a bit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246763) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Convert angle to clock time](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246765/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Reverse and square](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246779/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Is this a Function?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246796/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Halve the Falses](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246797/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Infinite Candle Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246805/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Random Points from 2D Donut Distribution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246831/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Sum of Two Squares](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246833/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Rotate a number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246857/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Product over a range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246861/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Range, Reverse, Sum!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246862/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Collatz Encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246865/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Biohazard Symbol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246880/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [How far away is n to the next power of b?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246887/107299) by [Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/seggan)
- [Pi == 3.2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246892/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [How compactly can your language perform accurate numerical integration?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246894/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Is Wally There?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246904/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Draw the Ionising Radiation Hazard Symbol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196312/draw-the-ionising-radiation-hazard-symbol/246913#246913) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Draw the flag of Bangladesh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246915/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Draw the national flag of Iceland](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246919/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Draw the Swiss flag](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246921/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Rounding a Range](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246944/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Count the number of ones in an unsigned 16-bit integer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246946/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Is this a Jordan matrix?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246953/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Draw the Ionising Radiation Hazard Symbol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246914/107299) by [Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/seggan)
- [Subtract the next numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246960/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Reverse Array Sum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246993/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Reverse Maths Cycles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246994/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Reverse Deltas of an Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246995/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Inverse Deltas of an Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246996/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Split a list evenly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247000/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Bit-Reversal Permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247002/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Multiplicative undelta](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247003/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Chunk + Enumerate a list of digits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247006/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Cover up zeroes in a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247009/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Does it oscillate periodically?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247010/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Are All the Items the Same?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247029/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Check if a matrix is Zarankiewicz-maximal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247062/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Print 0 to 100 without 1-9 characters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247186/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Palindromic Powers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/247182/palindromic-powers) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Draw the Archimedean spiral](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247265/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Sort by Multiplying](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247286/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Is it an Elementary Matrix?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247315/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [There's more than one way to skin a set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247412/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [There's more than one way to skin a set](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247424/68261) by [fireflame241](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68261/fireflame241)
- [Crossing a lily pond](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247510/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Smallest subset of characters required for Turing Completeness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247545/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Find the nth Fibonacci number, where n is the mth Fibonacci number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247646/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Add an array with itself](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247648/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [How long is my number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247660/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Equal numbers in a sub-array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247662/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Who needs 8 bits for one character?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247679/92689) by [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689)
- [Divisible subset sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247742/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Previous Fibonacci number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247855/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [How even is a number?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247899/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [Check membership of an infinite list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247903/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- [What's the best die to roll?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248055/96039) by [Aiden Chow](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/96039/aiden-chow)
- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant tips posted in May 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<tip summary>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```

## List of relevant challenges posted in May 2022

- *add entries in the form:*

  ```
  [<challenge title>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/<answer-ID>) by [username](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>)
  ```